# Validation of asp.net identity password

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net mvc application, in which I used the `Asp.net identity`. I implemented this method to validate a collaborator ( customisation of user) fields :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public bool ValidateCollaborateur(CollaborateurModel item)
    {
        if (item.Username == null || item.Email == null) return false;
        if (UserManager.FindByEmail(item.Email) != null) return false; 

        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }
```

`item` contains the `password` property of asp.net identity user, so it must contains

1. Special character
2. number
3. Lower character
4. Upper character

I'd like to validate the `item.Password` field as described above.

1. How can I accomplish this task?
2. Is a method of asp.net identity password validation exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build an expression that matches your criteria:

```
 var password = "password_to_test";

 if (password.Any("!@#$%^&*".Contains)
  && password.Any(char.IsDigit)
  && password.Any(char.IsLower)
  && password.Any(char.IsUpper))
  {
      //valid!
  }
```

using this approach, you can add and remove any criteria easily without having to rework the validation.  It also gives you the ability to split out your conditions, and return an invalid password to the user with a specific reason.

Comment: for the special characters, is it the full list? I mean `_` , `-` ........ are special characters too!!

Comment: feel free to tweak it as needed.  This is just a quick sample I drew up to get you started.